How can I update the index of a navbar in flutter with go_router and riverpod when the user do pop with system back button?
I'm working on an application that uses GoRouter for navigation and Riverpod for state management. My code works fine, but I'm having an issue trying to update the index of the navbar when the user goes back using the system button or gestures in Android or iOS.
I have an instance of GoRouter in a provider:
part 'app_router.g.dart';

@riverpod
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  GoRouter build() {
    return GoRouter(
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/login',
          builder: (context, state) => const LoginView(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/register',
          builder: (context, state) => const RegisterView(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/forgot-password',
          builder: (context, state) => const ForgotPasswordView()
        ),
        ShellRoute(
          builder: (context, state, child) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: child,
              bottomNavigationBar: const NavBar(),
            );
          },
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/',
              builder: (context, state) => const HomeView(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: '/settings',
              builder: (context, state) => const SettingsView(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: '/profile',
              builder: (context, state) => const ProfileView(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

And then I have the navbar:
class NavBar extends ConsumerWidget {
  const NavBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final navBarIndex = ref.watch(navBarIndexNotifierProvider);

    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: navBarIndex,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          label: 'Settings',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          label: 'Profile',
        ),
      ],
      onTap: (index) {
        ref.read(navBarIndexNotifierProvider.notifier).updateIndex(index);
        context.push(
          index == 0
              ? '/'
              : index == 1
                  ? '/settings'
                  : '/profile',
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

With the provider:
part 'navbar_provider.g.dart';

@riverpod
class NavBarIndexNotifier extends _$NavBarIndexNotifier {
  @override
  int build() {
    return 0;
  }

  void updateIndex(int index) {
    state = index;
  }
}

How can I make the navbar index update correctly when the user goes back? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
I have tried with GoRouterObserver
part 'app_router.g.dart';

@riverpod
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  GoRouter build() {
    observers: [GoRouterObserver(
        ref.read(navBarIndexNotifierProvider.notifier),
      )],
    routes[]
  }
}


class GoRouterObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  final navBarIndexNotifier;

  GoRouterObserver(this.navBarIndexNotifier);

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('MyTest didPop: $route');
    final currentRoute = route.settings.name;
    switch (currentRoute) {
      case '/':
        break;
      case '/settings':
        navBarIndexNotifier.updateIndex(1);
        break;
      case '/profile':
        navBarIndexNotifier.updateIndex(2);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}

I also tried to use PopScope but I don't think I implemented it well because I didn't understand how to use it. As with WillPopScope, but it is already deprecated.

What you are doiing may work, but it is against the way GoRouter is intended to be used. push is imperative navigation, while GoRouter is suposed to be used for declarative navigation (go). What do you want to achieve apart from detecting "pop", why are you using push?

This is my first time using go_router and so I don't really know how to do what I want to do. I started using go instead of push, but the problem was that when I tried to go back with the system button it closed the application instead of going to the previous view. So I decided to use push. And the other problem I have is how to update the navbar status when using the back button. Is there a better way to do it?
